# An extension of the Four 4's game

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

When I was in lower school I remember playing the Four $4$'s game and we got to around $10$. For those of you who don't know the Four $4$'s game is one where you have to use four $4$'s and you have to construct an equation using multiplication, division, addition and subtraction.

This new game, however, is a bit more interesting. Firstly, you can only use the previously mentioned operations, as well as raising to a power (provided it uses the number $4$ such as $4^4$), you can use the factorial operation, and you can take the square root (ignore the $\frac12$). There is no concatenation or decimals, as well as no logarithms, functions (such as the Gamma Function), primordial numbers, or double, triple etc factorials. And the question is: **What is the smallest Natural Number you can't create?**

Just wanted to clarify by giving an example:
$3 = \sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4} - \frac{4}{4}$

Comment: What numbers have you created?

Comment: I will tell you the answer is in between 1 - 100 (Just got off a long-haul flight).

Comment: José Carlos Santos: I found the smallest number, at least I believe it is maybe I have not been creative enough. This is more of just a general idea for a pass-time.  I will say there are a few numbers in the 30's that took a while.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the answer though, I just don't want to spoil it for anyone else by giving it away in the comments.

Comment: It seems like one should be able to brute-force it.  Write a formal language for the acceptable strings, and evaluate them all; if I'm not mistaken, there are only finitely many.  Wrong - I forgot the unary operators.  You can take factorials forever.

Comment: I cannot get $\Large{39,\; 41, \;43}$. Who can get any of them?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what did you get for 33, it took me at least 30 minutes.

Comment: $${\large{33}} = \dfrac{64+2}{2} = \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{24}+\sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{4}} = \dfrac{ \left(\sqrt{ \sqrt{ \sqrt{4} } }\right) ^{4!} + \sqrt{4}}{\sqrt{4}}.$$

Comment: Update: $\large{41}$ is possible: $${\large 41} = \sqrt{1681} = \sqrt{\dfrac{24+40320}{24}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{4!+(4+4)!}{4!}}.$$

Comment: Is there a list of functions we can use? I know that when I am playing this game in class, we always debate over $n-th$ root function as the square root technically has a two in it. What about floor and ceiling functions? I feel it would be helpful to define which functions are viable.

Comment: I think you mean "primorial number", not "primordial".

Comment: According to [Murderous Maths](http://www.murderousmaths.co.uk/books/4x4ans.htm), from $1$ to $40$, $1, 10, 11, 13, 21, 26, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 38$ and $39$ are missing solutions (following the rules here).

Comment: Presumably binomial coefficient notation is excluded.  Otherwise $39 = 24 + 15 = 4! + \binom{4+\sqrt{4}} {4}$.

Comment: Well, that notation is basically $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ hence it would use a lot more 4's. However, you could argue that multiplication is the addition of many 4's hence it too uses many 4's.

Comment: $113$ is supposed to be pretty hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's record (at least one of possible) solutions in the table.

In additional column we will mark which extension was used: $\hat{}$ or $\sqrt{\phantom{w}}$ or $!$ (in addition to mentioned classic $+\;-\;\times \;/$ version).

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
number & formula & extension \\
\hline
1 & 4-4+4/4 & \\
2 & (4\cdot 4) /(4+4) & \\
3 & (4+4+4) / 4 & \\
4 & 4 + (4-4)*4 & \\
5 & (4 + 4\cdot 4)/4 & \\
6 & 4 + (4+4)/4 & \\
7 & 4+4 - 4/4 & \\
8 & 4+4+4-4 & \\
9 & 4+4 + 4/4 & \\
10 & 4 + 4+ 4/\sqrt{4} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
11 &  (4!+4!-4) /4 & ! \\
12 & 4\cdot(4 - 4/4) & \\
13 & (4!+4!+4) / 4 & ! \\
14 & 4\cdot 4 - 4/\sqrt{4} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
15 & 4\cdot 4 - 4/4 & \\
16 & 4+4+4+4 & \\
17 & 4\cdot 4 + 4/4 & \\
18 & 4\cdot 4 + 4/\sqrt{4} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
19 & 4! - 4 - 4/4 & ! \\
20 & 4\cdot(4 + 4/4) & \\
21 & 4! - 4 + 4/4 & ! \\
22 & 4\cdot 4 + 4 + \sqrt{4} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
23 & (4\cdot 4! - 4)/4 & ! \\
24 & 4+4 + 4\cdot 4 & \\
25 & 4! + 4\cdot(4-4)! & ! \\
26 & 4! - 4 + 4!/4 & ! \\
27 & 4! + 4!/(4+4) & ! \\
28 & 4\cdot(4+4) - 4 & \\
29 & 4! + 4 + 4/4 & ! \\
30 & 4(4+4) - \sqrt{4} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
31 & ((4!/4)! +4!)/4! & ! \\
32 & 4\cdot 4 + 4\cdot 4 & \\
33 & \left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4^{4!}}}}+\sqrt{4}\right) / \sqrt{4} & \hat{},!,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
34 & 4(4+4) + \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
35 & 4! + (4!-\sqrt{4})/\sqrt{4} & !,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
36 & 4\cdot(4+4) + 4 & \\
37 & 4! + (4!+\sqrt{4})/\sqrt{4} & !,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
38 & 4! - \sqrt{4} + 4\cdot 4 & !, \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
39 & ????????????????????? & \\
40 & 4 (4+4+\sqrt{4}) & \sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
41 & \sqrt{(4!+(4+4)!)/4!} & !,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
42 & 4! + 4! - 4!/4 & ! \\
43 & ????????????????????? & \\
44 & 4! + 4 + 4\cdot 4 & ! \\
45 & (4!/4)!/ (4\cdot 4) & ! \\
46 & 4!+4!-4/\sqrt{4} & !,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} \\
47 & 4!+4! - 4/4 & ! \\
48 & 4 \cdot (4+4+4) & \\
49 & 4!+4! + 4/4 & ! \\
50 & 4!+4!+4/\sqrt{4} & !,\sqrt{\phantom{w}} 
\end{array}

---

To know which (real) numbers admit $4$ $4$'s formula, 
one can use this simple algorithm:

build set $A_1$ of numbers, which can be obtained from one $4$.
Since $\sqrt{\phantom{w}}$ and $!$ are allowed (unary "operations"), the set $A_1$ isn't finite.
We will stop at some reasonable step.
Say, let the set $A_1$ is
$$
A_1 = \{ 4, 4!, \sqrt{4}=2, \sqrt{4!}, \sqrt{\sqrt{4}}, \sqrt{\sqrt{4!}}, \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}},  \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{4}}}} \}.
$$

Then we build set $A_2$: set of numbers which can be obtained from two $4$'s:
for any $a\in A_1$, for any $b\in A_1$ add to $A_2$ following numbers:

- $a+b$,
- $|a-b|$,
- $a\cdot b$,
- $a/b$ (if $b\ne 0$),
- $b/a$ (if $a\ne 0$),
- $a^b$ (if $a\ne 0$),
- $b^a$ (if $b\ne 0$).

Then update the set $A_2$ with factorials (of its old small integer elements) and square roots of its old elements.
We can repeat this update few times.

And clear the set $A_2$ of duplicates.

The set $A_3$ is derived this way from $A_1$ and $A_2$.

The set $A_4$ (final set!) has $2$ parts:

a) part $1$ - derived from $A_2$ and $A_2$;

b) part $2$ - derived from $A_1$ and $A_3$.

---

There is small chance that when extend $A_1$ with more roots/factorials ($A_2,A_3,A_4$ too), we can describe more numbers from the range $1,\ldots, 100$; but chances are really small since repeated roots tend to $1$, repeated factorials tend to $\infty$.

Comment: Wow, this great. I wonder if there's a pattern between say using 3's instead of 4's. Or what is the first number you can't make from 5 4's etc? I think it's an interesting way to see the relation between the maximum number possible, and the binary and unary operations.

Comment: If use four $3$'s, then it's hard to get $23$, $31$, $32$ for me. About five $4$'s: I'll able to answer a bit later.

Comment: @John Miller: update: on four 3's: $23 = \dfrac{(3!)!}{3!\cdot 3!}+3$, $\;31 = \sqrt{(3!)! + \dfrac{(3!)!+3}{3}}$, so numbers $32,44,47$ are first hard examples there. On five 4's: such first hard examples are: $135, 159, 161, 189$ (according to my calculations).